# Finding a fixed point of a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K\cdot |x-y|$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ fulfill $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K\cdot |x-y|$ $\forall x,y \in [a,b]$, $0<K<1$.

Prove $\exists! z\in [a,b]$ such that $f(z)=z$.

I am really lost here. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: This is sometimes known as the contraction mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS** try to see that $f$ is continuous and continuous function $g(x)= f(x) - x $ has a zero ...  for proving this consider sign of  $g(a)$ and $g(b)$...and use **intermediate value theorem**

suppsoe $y,z$ be two such point ...then $|z-y| =|f(z)-f(y)|< |z-y|$..so such a $z$ is unique

Comment: I didn't manage to prove continuity but uniform continuity. Is that okay?

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly trying to say...can you tell it clearly?? for proving continuity prove that {$f(x_n)$} converges whenever {$x_n$} converges

Comment: I did prove uniform continuity... Not continuity..

Comment: this implies continuity, by definition

Comment: How can I show uniqueness ?

Comment: If $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = y$, what does the inequality $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \ldots$ tell you?